# How do you code double up arrow?

Tags: support, mathjax

If you type `x^\Uparrow` you get $x^\Uparrow$ which  is not as clear as $\Uparrow$. (It could be my monitor's low resolution.)

Comment: Compare $x^{\Large \Uparrow}$ and $x^{\large \Uparrow}$ and $x^{\Uparrow}$

Comment: Which is to say  
x^{\Large \Uparrow} and x^{\large \Uparrow} and x^{\Uparrow}

Comment: @Peter, one would hope they'll right-click on the $\LaTeX$ expressions to figure out how it was done... ;)

Comment: @J.M.: personally I would prefer `$x^{\displaystyle \Uparrow}$` instead if one wants to override the implicit `\scriptstyle` that makes the arrows smaller.

Comment: @Ｊ.M. I had no idea you could do that :O

Comment: @Willie, fair point. :)